Show startup window while the main window loads
I have the below code. The GetMode method performs some operations that take some time to complete, for this reason, I want the startup window to show up and display a message and an animation while the main window loads inside the GetMode method. The startup window shows up but does not show any content, it stays blank and waits until the GetMode finishes, shows the content for an instant, closes immediately and the main window shows up.
I tried listening to the Activated event but I got the same result, I tried listening to the Loaded event of the content inside the startup window but got also the same result, if I await GetMode I get an exception that doesn't even have a message, also I resolve the main view via dependency injection and in the main window I listen to system events like battery and connectivity changes that come from background threads so I use DispatcherQueue class to update the UI, this also throws an exception if I await GetMode since the Dispatcher Queue class returns null inside Task.Run.
In WPF, this is pretty straightforward with the Show and Hide methods in a window, but in WinUI3 it's not that easy (of course not, silly me that expects it to be lol).
private Window _mainWindow;
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    var startupWindow = new StartupWindow();
    startupWindow.Activate();

    GetMode();

    startupWindow.Close();
    _mainWindow.Activate();
}

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

I had a similar problem with a login page. I have a button event here but maybe your should have an event based on when the startup Window Closes. The Main Window below will only be launched after the loginButton is clicked on the startWindow.
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
     var startUpWindow = App.GetService<LoginWindow>();
     startUpWindow.LoginButton.Click += async (sender, e) => {
     base.OnLaunched(args);
     await App.GetService<IActivationService>().ActivateAsync(args);
     startUpWindow.Close();
     };
     startUpWindow.Activate();
}


Thanks! Waiting on a button event does work but I rather not have the user clicking a button. I found that placing await Task.Delay(100); right after startupWindow.Activate(); makes the window work. It seems like an ugly random fix but the startup window is only a nice-to-have thing so it works for me.

You should try the SplashScreen on the WinUIEx NuGet package.
For example:
SplashScreen.xaml
<winuiex:SplashScreen
    x:Class="WinUIDemoApp.SplashScreen"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUIDemoApp"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:winuiex="using:WinUIEx"
    Title="SplashScreen"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <ProgressRing IsActive="True" />
    </Grid>

</winuiex:SplashScreen>

SplashScreen.xaml.cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WinUIDemoApp;

public sealed partial class SplashScreen : WinUIEx.SplashScreen
{
    public SplashScreen(Type window) : base(window)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Func<Task>? Function { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnLoading()
    {
        if (Function is not null)
        {
            await Function.Invoke();
        }
        
        await base.OnLoading();
    }
}

and use it like this:
App.xaml.cs
private Window? Window { get; set; }

protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    var splashScreen = new SplashScreen(typeof(MainWindow))
    {
        Function = async () =>
        {
            // You logic here.
            await GetMethod();
        }
    };

    splashScreen.Completed += (s, e) => Window = e;
}

